# MeshPartBuilder transparent TextureRegions

Tags: libgdx, textures

I'm drawing ModelInstances in a ModelBatch with LibGDX, but the textures of the models are deformed and their transparent pixels are opaque. I'm using the texture packer [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeZAG.png) to produce an atlas. I then assign the TextureRegion from the atlas to a Material in order to create the MeshPartBuilder:

```
GameModels() {
    int attr = VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal | VertexAttributes.Usage.TextureCoordinates;

    TextureRegion texture = textureAtlas.findRegion("cactus");

    modelBuilder.begin();
    MeshPartBuilder meshPartBuilder = modelBuilder.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr,
            new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(texture),
                    ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(ItemType.CACTUS.color)));

    BoxShapeBuilder.build(meshPartBuilder, 1f,1f,1f);

    cubeModel = modelBuilder.end();
}
```

But the rendering from the created Model produces this:
[A cropped and opaque texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVlfP.png)

I want to produce a rendering of the texture that respects the texture and is transparent, like the second image from the second link. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. If it is about the TextureRegion part then you should use the MeshPartBuilder#setUVRange(TextureRegion) method instead (see http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/MeshPartBuilder.html#setUVRange-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion-). If it is about transparency then you should add the BlendingAttribute (see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Material-and-environment#blendingattribute).

Comment: Thank you ! Adding the blendingAttribute corrected the [problem with the texture](http://imgur.com/a/L7gil), I will now try to clarify the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding a BlendingAttribute to the Material the texture supports now the transparency from the TextureRegion.

```
BlendingAttribute blendingAttribute = new BlendingAttribute();
blendingAttribute.opacity = 1f;

...

MeshPartBuilder meshPartBuilder = modelBuilder.part("box", GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, attr,
            new Material(textureAttribute, blendingAttribute));
```

[Corrected rendering of the texture with blending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEFvE.png)